# Struggling with Reusable Functions to Handle Frames

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

> I am creating a reusable function to handle frames, and want to click on "I'm not Robot" check-box on fantasy11 website. It's throwing an exception - . **Please help.**.

I have tried a lot, but struggling to get the correct results.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class section9frames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://fantasycricket.dream11.com/IN/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        int number=findframenumber(driver,By.xpath(".//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']/div[5]"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(number);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']/div[5]")).click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        int number1=findframenumber(driver,By.xpath(".//*[@id='recaptcha-verify-button']"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(number1);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='recaptcha-verify-button']")).click();

    }

    public static int findframenumber(WebDriver driver,By by) {
        int i;
        int framecount=driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();

        for (i=0;i<framecount;i++) {
            driver.switchTo().frame(i);
            int count=driver.findElements(by).size();
            if(count>0) {
                break;
            } else{

            }
        }
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        return i;
    }
}
```

[Please have a look into the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpKiF.jpg)

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: 1

Comment: So you are writing code to create a robot to get around the feature that is trying to prevent robots... don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on my own API wrapper for common WebElement interactions.  I solved this problem through a Decorator Pattern using the java.lang.reflect.Proxy class.

```
  public void exampleUse() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        int frameIdInt = 1;
        String frameId ="someFrame";
        WebElement frameRef = driver.findElement(By.id(frameId));
        WebElement inFrameByIntId = frameSafeElement(driver, frameIdInt, By.id("element"));
        WebElement inFrameByStringId = frameSafeElement(driver, frameId, By.id("element"));
        WebElement inFrameByReference = frameSafeElement(driver, frameRef, By.id("element"));

        // Now you should be able to do anything you want with the WebElement through the WebElement API. All
        // invocations will go through the Proxy instance below which will switch to the frame, resolve the WebElement
        // reference in context of the frame, perform the desired function against the resolved WebElement, switch back
        // to default context, and return the results from the delegate invocation.
    }

    private final WebElement frameSafeElement(final WebDriver driver, final String frameId, final By lookup) {
        return (WebElement) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{WebElement.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                try {
                    driver.switchTo().frame(frameId);
                    WebElement element = driver.findElement(lookup);
                    return method.invoke(element, args);
                } finally {
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }
            }
        }) ;
    }
    private final WebElement frameSafeElement(final WebDriver driver, final int frameId,  final By lookup) {
        return (WebElement) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{WebElement.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                try {
                    driver.switchTo().frame(frameId);
                    WebElement element = driver.findElement(lookup);
                    return method.invoke(element, args);
                } finally {
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }
            }
        }) ;
    }
    private final WebElement frameSafeElement(final WebDriver driver, final WebElement frameReference,  final By lookup) {
        return (WebElement) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{WebElement.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                try {                    
                    driver.switchTo().frame(frameReference);
                    WebElement element = driver.findElement(lookup);
                    return method.invoke(element, args);
                } finally {
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }
            }
        }) ;
    }
```

For your example above, you'll need to make the utility methods static to reference them from your main, but it would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://fantasycricket.dream11.com/IN/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    int number=findframenumber(driver,By.xpath(".//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']/div[5]"));
    WebElement firstFrameObject = frameSafeElement(driver, number, By.xpath(".//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']/div[5]"));
    firstFrameObject.click();

    int number1=findframenumber(driver,By.xpath(".//*[@id='recaptcha-verify-button']"));
    WebElement secondFrameObject = frameSafeElement(driver, number, By.xpath(".//*[@id='recaptcha-verify-button']"));
    secondFrameObject.click()
 }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Jeremiah for quick solution...It would be great if you would help me to correct **findframenumber(WebDriver driver,By by)**

Comment: I think it would be in the spirit of StackOverflow if you took the issues with findframenumber to another post, since that would be outside the scope of your original query about reusable iframe methods.  Please take note of the comments the others left and offer more detail into the problem and what you're trying to achieve. The more specific you are about the issue, the easier it is for people to understand the problem and offer assistance.  I'll try to keep an eye out for that thread and offer what assistance I can, but that particular effort is a little out of my wheelhouse.   Best of Luck

Comment: I just want to create the reusable function that will **traverse each frame** and try to locate the element by checking element availability using **size()** method of List interface. Function should return index.                    I know it's not efficient way if we consider performance. I was just trying to perform the frame finding in different way.

Comment: There's an issue with this general logic though.  It looks like you're trying to dynamically find each frame, but when you use them you're searching for specific content tied to that frame. Based on your implementation the first frame you want div[5] and the second you want a button.  You can't be agnostic and specific in the same implementation without more abstraction.  Even with that I'm not sure if it's possible from the context I have.  I would strongly suggest trying to re-assess what it is you're looking for and make sure you're going about it correctly.